# Yii2 File upload is not working with large files

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2

I am trying to upload image file to web server. I am using Yii2 framework. I am able to upload small files without any problem, whereas if I am uploading large file, It is not getting upload. I am able to see progress bar in browser while file is getting uploaded. but  after completion of file upload, file is not saved on server as well as  browser displays blank screen instead of index.php but debug message (Check point 1 **) is logged in log file.

Here is code fragment for your reference.

```
        if ($model->load($_POST) && $model->save()) {
        $arrFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file_location');
        if (!empty($arrFile)) {
            $model->file_location = $arrFile;
            $strFileName = $model->file_location->baseName . '.' . $model->file_location->extension;
            Yii::error('Check point 1 ************* '. $strFileName);
            if ($model->file_location->saveAs('uploads/newsletters/' . $strFileName)) {
                $model->file_location = $strFileName;
                $model->save();
                return $this->redirect('index');
                //return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
        } else {
            return $this->redirect('index');  //$this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]); 
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please check your server max file upload size?

Comment: @ManikandanS : I have not specified any size limit in code. Also disk space available more than is 5GB.

Comment: You have to follow @MoneerKamal instruction as below answer and after changing the value please restart the apache server.

Comment: I have  max_execution_time=120, upload_max_filesize=32M settings on my server. I am trying to upload 2 - 5 MB file on server and failing to upload. To uploading 2 MB file it took 1 min 5 Sec.  Hence I am thinking to update max_input_time from 60 to 180 Sec.  Any inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check this in your php.ini

```
  upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

and edited to be as larg as you need

Comment: @Manikandan and Moneer:  Thanks for your support. This solution worked. Somehow this parameter was not reflecting on my shared web server, but with the help of server team I have changed it from 2M to 5M. File I was trying to upload was 2.6M.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this in the php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 30
```

Or

In your php script:

```
set_time_limit(180); // Set max execution time 3 minutes.
```